# Famous modern-era academics without academic degrees?

Tags: degree

Are the any famous or well-known (today-living) researchers without academic degrees working as professors or permanent staff members?

There are two related questions:

- [PhD without previous academic degree: truth or myth?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17841/phd-without-previous-academic-degree-truth-or-myth)
- [Is it possible to obtain a Master's degree without Bachelor's degree?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26786/is-it-possible-to-obtain-a-masters-degree-without-bachelors-degree)

However, I am curious about the no-degree (past upper secondary school, i.e. no BSc, MSc, PhD, etc) case.

Comment: What about a degree in an unrelated field (e.g. math professor with a degree in history), would that count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regard to your question's topic, at least two relevant terms come to mind: [lay scholar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lay_scholar) and [autodidact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodidacticism). Once we establish the right terminology, it is not too difficult to find information that you're looking for. In particular, [this Wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_autodidacts) and [this list](http://www.autodidactic.com/profiles/profiles.htm) seem to be rather comprehensive (you will have to filter the information to select the *modern-era* academics without degrees).

Answer (score -1):

Freeman Dyson does not have a PhD.

http://pipeline.corante.com/archives/2014/04/01/freeman_dyson_on_the_phd_degree.php

Comment: -1, Freeman Dyson has a Cambridge MA